# PowerApps new form: Display error msg if item exists in unique SP column?

Tags: error-handling, powerapp

I have a form that successfully creates a new SP list item if the unique column value is not being duplicated. If the user attempts to submit an item where that value already exists, the new item is not created. Good.

But on submit with this error condition, it just sits there and does nothing. OnFailure doesn't seem to do anything. I assumed creating a label and changing its visibility in the OnFailure event would work (LabelError.Visible=true).

How can I display something to the user to indicate the problem when SubmitForm fails?

Comment: I must be missing something very obvious. If SubmitForm fails for any reason, any possible reason, surely there is some functionality to tell the user "hey, that didn't work" so they aren't sitting there hammering the submit button over and over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Simply put any of the statements below in the OnFailure event:

Notify( "This value already exists...")  - should show a blue banner

Notify( "This value already exists...", Error )  - should show a red banner

Notify( "This value already exists...", Warning )   - should show an orange banner

Problem, I get a green banner with all the above, lol.

Reference:

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/showerror-function-is-changing-its-name-to-notify-as-it-learns-some-new-tricks/

Comment: Just tried it.
I confirm : Green in every case !
Let's say we like green ;-)